Как обрабатывать звук аудио файла через VST-плагин на Java
У меня есть VST плагин, который может обрабатывать звук. Также имеется Java проект (некоторое подобие DAW программы), к которому я бы хотел подключить этот плагин и чтобы он обрабатывал звук аудио файла в режиме реального времени. Я знаю про JVST Host, который может лишь запустить сам плагин. Также пробовал работать с JVST (ситуация аналогична). Можно ли как нибудь реализовать это, что бы можно было открыть плагин, изменить в нём что то, и эти изменения сразу бы отразились на аудио файле?
